# eclipse folder mapping question

Tags: eclipse, settings, directory

I know that `Eclipse` offers a way to map custom folders on my HDD *(for example, `C:\Projects\Lol\` if working under `Windows`)* as the folders of my project.

This can be achieved using the `Link the folder in the file system` option when performing `New->Folder` action.

However, I didn't find how to map the folders with **relative** *(not absolute)* paths. **Is this possible?**

---

I'm confused, because if mapping the folders with relative paths *(say, `../Lol/Include`)* is impossible, this makes sharing projects with such folders among my team impossible.

**How should I solve this?**

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to type in the relative path on your own? Also I remember that you can give paths relative to the project directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usally achieve this behavior by having a symbolic link on file-system level and adding it to the code repository. I don't know if it is THE way to go, but works perfectly well for me.

Any eclipse-only link is stored in the eclipse meta files and I doubt it's better checking them in because they will usually differ slightly from user to user.